# Location Tracking in Background

Tags: windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I am developing a windows phone app that uses users current location, I am making the app in 7 OS. My question is, Can I track the location in background, that is when the screen is locked? 
I know this is a possibility in wp8 as it provides us with GeoLocator class, but can I achieve this in wp7? I am basically making a runtracker app hence I would like my app to track the location even when its in background, is it really feasible?
Your help is always appreciated!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to keep the app running under lock screen, as it does, for example, Endomondo app.

Using [Idle Detection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx/css), you can keep the app on, although screen is locked, and you can keep on tracking the location. Actually, it is not running in background, but in the foreground. Just the screen is locked. So, be careful not to drain user's battery.

You have to set the [`PhoneApplicationService.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.applicationidledetectionmode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property to `Disabled`, for example in `InitializePhoneApplication()` method in *App.xaml.cs*:

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;
```

Note that there are special certification requirements for this type of apps. Refer to section 6.3 (Apps running under a locked screen) of the following page:

[Additional requirements for specific app types for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/hh184838%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Comment: I wrote this line in my page constructor, still it isn't tracking any location when app goes in background, I made the same sample using 8 OS, and found that the same GeoCoordinateWatcher class and its event works even when the app is in background, I am able to track the location and position changed event is also getting fired, how is it so? same class and different behavior in different os, is there any revision in the api?

Comment: But do you just lock the screen (lock button) or do you go home page first (Windows button)? I can't try it in a WP7 device now, but I use Endomondo app when I workout, and I'm pretty sure it works this way, in both WP7 and 8.

Comment: "PhoneApplicationService.ApplicationIdleDetectionMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled;" this line prevents the application from going in lock mode, but what if I press windows button? this wont work in this scenario, I was unable to debug the app after pressing windows key, but the app made in 8 OS was getting debugged even when the  start key was pressed.

Comment: If you press Windows button the app is deactivated. In WP8, location tracking apps can keep on running, but not in WP7. They are two different things, to run under lockscreen, or to run in background. While the former is available for both systems, the latter is only possible with WP8, and under certain conditions.

Comment: ok, I got it clear now, Wp7 isn't supporting location tracking under deactivated mode, but doing so in lock screen. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I got the same problem in one on my apps..
I don't think it' s feasible for wp7..
Bt if you want to do it with wp8 you can refer following link.
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

And to know about background supported and unsupported API's http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202942%28v=vs.105%29.aspx/css

Answer (score 1):

GeoCoordinateWatcher Class exists in WP7, but here is the documentation from MSDN -

> This API, used for obtaining the geographic coordinates of the device,
>   is supported for use in background agents, but **it uses a cached
>   location value instead of real-time data**. The cached location value is
>   updated by the **device every 15 minutes**.

More Info : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202962%28v=vs.105%29.aspx/css